# Proof on simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $E$ be a finite extension of $F$ and suppose that $[E:F] = p$ where $p$ is prime.
Prove that $E$ is a simple extension of $F$.

I really don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prime = very few divisors. Simple = very few intermediate extensions. In the material up to this question, have you come across a formula that relates the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, $\ G\ $ is a field with $\ F\le G\le E\ $. Then, we have $$[E:F]=[E:G]\cdot [G:F]$$
Since $\ [E:F]\ $ is prime, we get $\ E=G\ $ or $\ G=F\ $. Hence $\ G\ $ cannot be a proper intermediate field, hence the extension must be simple.

Comment: Ah, okay,  I did not think of this definition of simple extension. Thanks.